# Displaying the data from an array of objects in a React Native View

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array of objects like below, I need some guidance on how to map through it and return the data in a React Native Screen View. Scroll to the bottom to see what I want the View to look like. If you need more information let me know.

```
 [
  {
    "Monday": [
      [
        "12.00",
        "15.00"
      ],
      [
        "18.00",
        "22.00"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "Tuesday": [
      [
        "12.00",
        "22.00"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

The code used to produce above's array is as follows:

```
   const res = Object.values(
    outletStore.outletOpeningHours.reduce((acc: any, obj) => {
      if (!acc[obj.day]) {
        acc[obj.day] = { [obj.day]: [] };
      }
      acc[obj.day][obj.day].push([obj.to, obj.from]);
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
```

I need help getting the React Native screen to display the opening hours like below:

Monday: 12:00 - 15.00
18.00 - 22.00

Tuesday: 12:00 - 22.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the object key use `Object.keys()`, which returns the keys array of object.

Here is solution :

```js
const yourVariableName = [
  {
    Monday: [
      ['12.00', '15.00'],
      ['18.00', '22.00'],
    ],
  },
  {
    Tuesday: [['12.00', '22.00']],
  },
];
```

return view as below :

```js
{yourVariableName.map((item, index) => (
  <View key={index.toString()}>
    <Text>
      {Object.keys(item)[0]}:{' '}
      {item[Object.keys(item)[0]].map((time, timeIndex) => (
        <Text key={timeIndex}>
          {time[0]}
          {' - '}
          {time[1]}{' '}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </Text>
  </View>
))}
```